# Logstash with Windows shows JAVA error

Tags: java, ruby, windows, elasticsearch, logstash

Logstash is giving me this error: "Cannot find Java 1.5 or higher."

The command I'm running is "bin\logstash -f \mypath\logstash-simple.conf"

I DO NOT have ruby installed on my windows 10 computer.
I have JAVA my PATH. "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin"

How do I fix this issue? Do I need ruby?

Comment: On windows, you should use the logstash.bat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set both the Java_Home property and add in PATH property such as mentioned below:-

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151 
PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `JAVA_HOME` system variable, that needs to point to your Java installation directory.

Comment: i've done that and it keeps giving me this error now "could not find java; set JAVA_HOME or ensure java is in PATH" - JAVA is in both JAVA_HOME and PATH

Comment: note: JAVA_HOME must be set to the Java installation directory. See Yuvraj Gupta's answer for an example.